# ajax: Print the identified result only from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

a have a set of arrays in `json` as followed:

```
[{"id":"0","NameInData":"","name":"","type":"mf","greeting":"Bonjour","message":"GENERIC: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"1","NameInData":"alexis","name":"Alexis","type":"mf","greeting":"Bonjour Alexis","message":"ONE: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"2","NameInData":"laurence","name":"Laurence","type":"ff","greeting":"Hello Laurence","message":"TWO: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"3","NameInData":"francois","name":"Francois","type":"mm","greeting":"Konnichiwa Francois","message":"THREE: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"4","NameInData":"dirk","name":"Dirk","type":"mf","greeting":"Ni hao Dirk","message":"FOUR: Lorem ipsum."},
{"id":"5","NameInData":"coline","name":"Coline","type":"ff","greeting":"high 5! Coline","message":"FIVE: Lorem ipsum."}]}
```

I am able to identify the value of a key from this array, and `//do something` with it with the following code:

```
function getID(name){

    $.each(data,function(key,value){    //value = object.value (name)

        $.each(value,function(key1,value1){     //value1 = user name (actual names in array)

            // name is identified   
            if(value1 == content){    //content is the "name" user entered
                console.log(value.id);

                var name = value.name;                  
                $('#nameText').text(name);
                console.log("Name: " + name);

                var greeting = value.greeting;
                $('#greetingText').text(greeting);
                console.log("Greeting: " + greeting);

                return;

            }                   
        });

    });

                // name is unidentified, new user
                var name = content;     //content is the "name" user entered            
                $('#nameText').text(name);
                console.log("Name: " + name);               

                var greeting = data[0].greeting;
                $('#greetingText').text(greeting);
                console.log("Greeting: " + greeting);

                console.log('0');
                return;

}

getID(data);
return false;
```

I am trying to `//do other things` if the name is not unidentified within the list with the following code. However, as my array has 6 items, the output would be repeating the whole process 6 times, printing `0` where I would only want one output, one result (either, a name and its id has been identified and print what it is related to OR a name has not been recognised and the id would be set to 0 and print what it is related.)

You may find my full code in the link **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/otofg4h4/)**. It would be very nice if someone could tell me which part of my syntax is wrong please?

**UPDATED CODE FROM ANSWER [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/otofg4h4/1/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array containing only the elements in your original array which pass a test.  In this case, your test is "does this item's name match the name provided by the user?":

```
success: function(data) {
  var data = data || [];
  var results = data.filter(function(element, index, array) {
    if (element.name === $('#nameText').text(name)) {
      return (true);
    }

    return (false);
  });

  if (results[0]) {
    // an element in the array matched what the user entered
    console.log(results[0]);
  }
  else {
    // no name in the array matched $('#nameText').text(name)
    // set id to 0 or whatever
  }
}
```

This is not perfect code; among other things, it assumes `$.ajax()` always returns an array and that array does not contain duplicate names.  But it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: also, your JSFiddle contains your Google API key and secret.  That's really really bad.  Please consider creating a new JSFiddle without your API keys, and editing this question to link to the new JSFiddle instead.

Comment: Thanks @Dan O for your suggestion! I am using the API key and secret which could be generated once my code is working well:P The information on my API are only tested items, but thank you so much for your consideration :))) x

Comment: Can I ask another question please? My results/console are printing very slow... Is there a suggestion to the reason please? You may also find my updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/otofg4h4/1/ Cheers >< xxx